# mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp for clustering tomcat and ssl

Tags: java, tomcat, apache

Please tell me what is better in supporting clustering and ssl between mod_jk and mod_proxy_ajp.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this [FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding SSL, it should not make any difference if you use mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp. Especially if you offload SSL in apache and not in tomcat, the transport between httpd <-> tomcat (mod_jk/mod_proxy_ajp) would not be affected.

As mod_proxy_ajp is the newer solution (that grew out of mod_jk), the general advice would be to go for mod_proxy_ajp (at least I'd use this one).

Cheers,
Martin

PS: mod_jk and mod_proxy_ajp are load-balancing solutions. clustering is more referring to the part where sessions are replicated between several cluster nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, session replication is one aspect of clustering, and clustering also to do with how a client is dispatched certain instence (one tomcat instance) of a cluster, that is load balancing.

A cluster should be see from outsite as one sinlge entry point, and hence, there are good reasons to have SSL handling in a central loation, we call this "ssloffloading" or "ssl termination" at load balancer / apache.

More info about ssloffloading see this post:
http://milestonenext.blogspot.de/2012/09/ssl-offloading-with-modjk-part-1.html